# How to set "lineSep" for Azure Data Factory mapping data flow with UTF16LE input and document per line?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to read a UTF16-LE JSON file with a "document per line".  I During the read file I get the following exception.  I don't see a "lineSep" option in the portal.  How does one set this?

Operation on target dataflow1 failed:

```
{"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'source1': java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The lineSep option must be specified for the UTF-16LE encoding","Details":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The lineSep option must be specified for the UTF-16LE encoding\n\tat scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptionsInRead.checkedEncoding(JSONOptions.scala:153)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptions$$anonfun$34.apply(JSONOptions.scala:109)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptions$$anonfun$34.apply(JSONOptions.scala:109)\n\tat scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptions.<init>(JSONOptions.scala:109)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptionsInRead.<init>(JSONOptions.scala:133)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptionsInRead.<init>(JSONOptions.scala:139)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat.inferSchema(JsonFileFormat.scala:55)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:193)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource."}
```

Thanks!
Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UTF-16LE` JSON file encoding format is currently not supported in the Azure data factory.

You can go through this Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json#dataset-properties) for all the supported encoding types in JSON dataset in the Azure data factory.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, that is interesting since it is in the portal.  I tried UTF-16 since it is listed and it seems UTF-16 means UTF-16 with a BOM, and UTF-16LE does not expect a BOM.  Both validate and run successfully on a file that's a "setOfObjects", and both will import the schema from a sample file correctly, however, neither one actually reads any date during a run, or will read values in a debug session.  This is disappointing.